# Optimize script for extracting records from multiple files using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to extract records from multiple files using power shell, The script that i have written is iterating through each file and writing the records matching the pattern to an out file. however this is taking long time due to huge number of files

I would like to know if this can be optimized.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $sourcedirectory\*

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    $outfile = $files[$i].FullName + "_out" 
    Get-Content $files[$i].FullName| Select-String -Pattern "OB_[0-9]F_AHU*" | Set-Content $outfile
}


if (!(Test-Path -path $targetdirectory)) {New-Item $targetdirectory -Type Directory}
Move-Item -Path $sourcedirectory\*_out -Destination $targetdirectory
```

Comment: You'll likely want to look at PowerShell jobs or runspaces for a multithreaded approach. The module PoshRSJobs is useful; it provides a 'job-like' way to work with runspaces.

Comment: Thanks @Robin. Let me check it out

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using (`$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major`)?

Comment: $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major :  5

Answer (score 0):

Could you post some more details about what you are trying to accomplish?

At face value, here is a solution that parses each file in parallel. I'm not sure off the top of my head how many concurrent jobs it will use but this should get you started down this pathway.

Try this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $sourcedirectory\*

foreach -parallel ($file in $files) {
    $outfile = $file.FullName + "_out" 
    Get-Content $file.FullName | Select-String -Pattern "OB_[0-9]F_AHU*" | out-file -Append $outfile
}
```

As far as your overall goal, sometimes PowerShell is not the best tool for the job. Whenever you want to parse through large amounts of data you should consider dumping that data into a database. You could use something like SQL Express and upload your files 1 time ( the slow operation ) and then be able to parse that data drastically faster from then on. Since I don't know what you are trying to accomplish or what your data looks like, I can't give you a good idea as to whether this is worth it in your case.

Comment: I tried using -parallel, but its not working, here is the updated version. can you hint out as what is wrong.

`workflow test1 {
$files = Get-ChildItem $sourceDir\*
foreach -parallel ($file in $files) {
    $outfile = $file.FullName + "_out" 
    Get-Content $files[$i].FullName| Select-String -Pattern "OB_[0-9]F_AHU*" | Set-Content $outfile
}
}
`

Answer (score 0):

You can write the new files directly to the target directory instead of moving them from the source directory.

```
$sourceDir = "C:\users\you\documents\somefiles"
$targetDir = "C:\users\you\documents\somefiles\targetDir"

if( !(Test-Path $targetDir) ) {
    New-Item -Path $targetDir -ItemType d
}

( Get-ChildItem $sourceDir | Select-String -Pattern "OB_[0-9]F_AHU*" ) | 
    %{ New-Item -Path $targetDir -Name ($_.Filename + "_out") -Value $_.Line}
```

The output of Select-String will contain the FileName and Line where the match was found, which is all you need to create new files with New-Item inside of the Foreach block %{}.

A small improvement.